# How can I default the link always to the right path in master page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-applications

I'm, facing an issue here, I have set a link in the master page as below:

```
<a href="pgSummary.aspx" style="color:blue;padding:8px">Add/Eidt Summary</a>
```

when I'm inside the following link http://www.test.com/smartStaff/ it's working fine for me... but somehow if I click on other page like http://www.test.com/smartStaff/testfolder/pgOther.aspx, then clicked on the Add/Eidt Summary link again.. it will direct me to http://www.test.com/smartStaff/testfolder/pgSummary.aspx (which I expect it will redirect me to http://www.test.com/smartStaff/pgSummary.aspx).

Does anyone know how can I get the path link always direct to the right path?

Comment: I'd fix this in your post, but it was replicated a few times so I'm guessing it's how your code actually is. "Add/Eidt" should probably be "Add/Edit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify an absolute path using `~/...`, however, you'll need to add the `runat="server"` attribute to the tag.

You can also use a HyperLink control (with `runat="server"`) and set the `NavigateUrl` property to "~/...`.

This syntax won't work in a regular `<a>` tag without `runat="server"` because it won't get translated to your root path.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Page.ResolveUrl`.  In your case:

```
Page.ResolveUrl("~/smartStaff/pgSummary.aspx")
```